# Module requests Python

Tags: python, module

I am trying to use the requests module in a python script. I start by the import command and write the script however it is telling me that requests is not a module. Can anyone explain this to me? Is this not built in like "re" or do I have to import it in? I am new to python so any help would be great. Using Windows!

Thanks

Deirdre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is a 3rd party library. You can install it using `pip`.

```
pip install requests
```

And even if `re` is built-in, you have to `import` it in order to use it.

Comment: I am having problems with installing pip, I am using version 2.7.6 so I have to install it when I copy the file onto the notepad and save it as a py file a message come up about encoding so it wont allow me to run. any suggestions I'm am really struggling at this

Comment: @Deirdre `pip install requests` is a terminal command, it's not Python code. It looks like you're using Windows, so run it in the command prompt. You _may_ need to have Admin privileges (I don't use Windows).

Comment: yes I have that but for some reason when I go to install the pip package it just wont work for me, when I click on the pip installation a file opens with pages of binary information.. so I am wondering if anyone else has encountered this

Comment: What do you mean by "wont work for me"? Does it still throw the same error? Did you do `import requests`?

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks.. I have installed requests successfully. thanks you